# how to convert a date in dd/mm/yyyy format to UTC format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ

Tags: angular

I want to convert my date in dd/mm/yyyy format to UTC format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ. Could anyone tell me how can we do that in angular 6?

I have tried using Date getUTCDate() method but no luck

```
this.date = new Date(newSearchData.beginDateUPD);
newSearchData.beginDateUPD = this.date.getUTCDate();
```

if my date is 08/02/2019 (i.e. 8th feb 2019), the output should be 2019-02-07T18:30:00.000Z

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done by providing the input format and output format

```
fun getMyDate(date: String?, outputFormat: String?, inputFormat: String?): String {
        try {
            val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, Locale.getDefault())
            simpleDateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
            return SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat, Locale(mAppLanguage)).format(simpleDateFormat.parse(date))
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (ex: NullPointerException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
        return ""
    }
```

Now call this

```
getMydate("YOUR DATE IN STRING","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'","dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Remove UTC if required